# What is the difference between get() and direct assignment in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

`_articles` has the same type `StateFlow<PagingData<ArticleItemEntity>>` as `articles`

```kotlin
private var _articles by mutableStateOf(getPageDataFlow(ArticleQuery()))

val articles: StateFlow<PagingData<ArticleItemEntity>>
  get() = _articles
```

I want to compare the difference of the code below:

```kotlin
val articles: StateFlow<PagingData<ArticleItemEntity>>
  get() = _articles

val articles = _articles
```

`_articles`is an `MutableState` type, so I can modify it.

When I modify `_articles` and reassign a `StateFlow`, `get() = _articles` got the modified value, `val articles = _articles` will not change, why?

Comment: I’m pretty sure your first example is broken code. You shouldn’t use a Flow as the type of a State.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I opened a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76839956/how-to-use-room-pagging-jetpack-compose-to-modify-parameters-to-dynamically-ch) for this, can you explain there why `you shouldn’t use a Flow as the type of a State`, what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

The `get()` syntax on properties simply defines the getter for that property. The code you write there is executed every time you access the property. Properties with an overridden `get()` do not have a backing field.

The other syntax is initializing a property with a value during construction. That property will have a backing field, which is set in the constructor, with a default getter method that simply returns the property value. So that's why it won't reflect changes to the `_articles` field.

Comment: Did you notice in the first case they have a State of a StateFlow used as a property delegate?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand. My understanding is that they should both hold references to `_articles`, what has changed?

Comment: @SageJustus Yes, they both get the value of `_articles`, but at different times: the one-line version gets the value just once, at initialisation, and stores it thereafter; while the `get()` version gets afresh it every time you use `articles` — and since `_articles` is delegated and returns a different instance each time you get it, only the `get()` version will reflect that.