# How to use Room+ Pagging+ Jetpack Compose to modify parameters to dynamically change front-end data?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I'm using Paging + Room, below is the core code:
`Dao`

```kotlin
@RawQuery(observedEntities = [ArticleItemEntity::class])
fun pagingSourceRawQuery(rawQuery: SupportSQLiteQuery): PagingSource<Int, ArticleItemEntity>
```

`ViewModel`

```kotlin
private fun getPageDataFlow(query: ArticleQuery) =
    Pager(PagingConfig(pageSize = 20, enablePlaceholders = false)) {
      articleLocalRepository.list(query)
    }.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope).stateIn(
      scope = viewModelScope,
      started = SharingStarted.Eagerly,
      initialValue = PagingData.empty()
    )
```

Paging allows me to obtain data in the database in the form of Flow.

But if I want to modify the query parameters, it seems that I can only change the Flow, so here is how I do it:

I wrap Flow with MutableState type:

```kotlin
private var _articles by mutableStateOf(getPageDataFlow(ArticleQuery()))

val articles: StateFlow<PagingData<ArticleItemEntity>>
  get() = _articles
```

In this way, I can change the Flow by calling the `updateArticles` method, thereby changing the front-end data.

```kotlin
fun updateArticles(query: ArticleQuery) {   
  _articles = getPageDataFlow(query)
}
```

But I was told `You shouldn’t use a Flow as the type of a State`, so how to dynamically modify the query parameters to dynamically modify the foreground data, what is the best practice?

Comment: At first glance, I thought this would be a complete mess when you try to consume the incoming flows in the Composable. There is a `collectAsStateWithLifecycle` function that starts collecting a flow to use as State, but it doesn't provide any `key` like the `remember` function does for restarting it when needed. And in this case you would need to restart it each time there's a new flow. But maybe that happens automatically. The documentation is just vague about it. Maybe someone more knowledgeable about that can answer.

Comment: If it is actually a problem, then the solution would be to use a MutableStateFlow for _articles instead of MutableState.  To do this, you could change `_articles` to be `private val _articles = MutableStateFlow(ArticleQuery())` that is updated by the `updateArticles` function. Then the `articles` property could be `val articles = _articles.flatMapLatest { getPageDataFlow(it) }.stateIn(viewModelScope)`

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks, this worked for me. You might consider re-editing it a bit to make it an answer.